# Configure log4j2 by code - only - in case of missing configuration

Tags: java, log4j2

I want to configure the log4j2 logging framework by code **only** in case no configuration file was found during the initialization process.

I read the possibilities obout [Programmatic Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html). As for now I am able to detect that log4j was initialized without any configuration (`ConfigurationSource.NULL_SOURCE`) and activate my new default configuration programmatically. But in this case I still get the error message of the log4j2 Status Loggor about the missing configuration and I have to stop the current configuration and start my new one.

I wonder if it is not possible to use the `ConfigurationFactory` approach for my use case. But I do not know how to hook it into the initialization process to only get activated if no other configuration approach succeeded. I would like to leave the general configuration process and supported file types untouched.

My current approach is this

```
@Plugin(name="FooBarConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(0) // should be very low priority
public class FooBarConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {

    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        // what to return here if the factory should support 'missing' configuration file?
        return new String[] {"*"};
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(LoggerContext loggerContext, ConfigurationSource source) {
        System.out.println("Get FooBar Configuration..."); // never saw this so far :-(
        return ...;
    }
```

Thanks for any help

Franz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way which may not be perfect but I think it can meet your demand.

Here's a brief example:

**Log4j2.java**

```
package test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager;

public class Log4j2 {

  private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("hello");
  }
}
```

**CustomConfigurationFactory.java**

```
package test;

import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Order;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.AppenderComponentBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.RootLoggerComponentBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;

@Plugin(name = "CustomConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(0)
public class CustomConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {

  private static Configuration createConfiguration(
      final String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
    builder.setConfigurationName(name);

    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder =
        builder
            .newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE")
            .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
    appenderBuilder.add(
        builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "%level: %msg%n"));
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);

    RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLoggerBuilder = builder.newRootLogger(Level.DEBUG);
    rootLoggerBuilder.add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout"));

    builder.add(rootLoggerBuilder);
    return builder.build();
  }

  @Override
  public Configuration getConfiguration(
      final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource source) {
    return getConfiguration(loggerContext, source.toString(), null);
  }

  @Override
  public Configuration getConfiguration(
      final LoggerContext loggerContext, final String name, final URI configLocation) {
    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
    return createConfiguration(name, builder);
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
    return new String[] {".code"}; // IMPORTANT
  }
}
```

Then create an empty file named **log4j2.code** in `src/main/resources`.

Note:

The most important thing is to ensure that the the `suffix` of your custom log4j2 configuration resource file is corresponding to the return value of the `CustomConfigurationFactory.getSupportedTypes` method.

---

**UPDATE**

If log4j2 cann't find the `CustomConfigurationFactory` plugin, try to enable annotation processing.

Comment: +q Placing some kind of marker file would be OK for me. Unfortunately I noticed that I can not ensure to be the first one who calls the Logger in my context, thus the ConfigurationFactory solution probably will not work as the log4j2 default configuration would be done already, right?

Comment: There's no need to invoke `PluginManager.addPackage`  method because `PluginProcessor` in log4j-core-2.*.jar will scan custom plugins automatically. You can have a try.

Comment: Nice hint about the plugin detection. Did not know that.